# How to position a tilted/skewed shape of unknown height in CSS?

Tags: css, layout, sass, css-transforms

### Problem

I need to code a design like in image below in CSS. In addition to pure CSS I also have Sass at my disposal.

**Note that the solution needs to be responsive. The angle is fixed (14 degrees), while the distance *x* is not, because it depends on the height of the container (which will be different on different screen widths).**

[image: Layout with 2 tilted areas]

### Fixed height

The fixed height version is not a problem:

#### HTML

```html
<section class="container">
  <p class="left">
    Some text spanning multiple lines
  </p>
  <p class="right">
    Some text spanning multiple lines
  </p>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
@use "sass:math";

$trapezium-skew-angle: -14deg;

@mixin orange-background {
  position: relative;

  // Needs to use pseudo-element to be able to render it
  // below the trapezium's layer
  &::before {
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}

@function trapezium-shift($trapezium-height) {
  @return (-1 * math.tan($trapezium-skew-angle) * $trapezium-height) / 2;
}

@mixin trapezium($height, $width) {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

  &::after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1 * trapezium-shift($height);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: $width;
    background-color: blue;
    transform: skew($trapezium-skew-angle);
  }
}

@mixin column {
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  @include orange-background;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 300px;
}

.left {
  @include column;
  @include trapezium($height: 300px, $width: 50%);
}

.right {
  @include column;
}
```

### Responsiveness

The problem is that my implementation needs to be responsive. When the screen height changes, the height of the container will change too and so will change the value of `trapezium-shift` (which is marked as *x* on the image). Sass runs at build-time, so there is no way for Sass to know the height of the container.

### Question

Do you know about any possible solution to this?

Comment: the angle need to be fixed or the distance?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The angle needs to be fixed, the distance _x_ is dynamic. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to consider a big element with a triangular shape where the width/height is set considering the angle you want to use.

Here is an example to illustrate:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh; /* dynamic height */
  background:blue;
  overflow:hidden; /* hide the overflow of the big shape */
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
}
.container > * {
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container > *:last-child {
  background:orange;
  position: relative;
}
.container > *:last-child::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  right:calc(100% - 0.5px); /* a litte less than 100% to avoid a gap issue */
  top:0;
  height:130vh; /* a big height, 100vh should be enough but a bit bigger won't hurt */
  width:calc(130vh * 0.249328); /* height x tan(14deg) */
  background:inherit;
  clip-path:polygon(0 100%,100% 100%,100% 0); /* triangle shape */
  
  opacity:0.9; /* to illustrate the shape */
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <p class="left">
    Some text spanning multiple lines
  </p>
  <p class="right">
    Some text spanning multiple lines
  </p>
</section>
```

Another idea with the same trick but using `box-shadow` and less of code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh; /* dynamic height */
  background:blue;
  overflow:hidden; /* hide the overflow of the big shape */
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
}
.container > * {
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
}
.container > *:last-child {
  background:orange;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 100vw orange; /* a very big box shadow*/
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0, 100% 150vh,calc(-0.249328 * 150vh) 150vh); 
  /*  the clip-path will cut a shape like below
            (0 0)   _______  (100% 0)
                   /       |
                  /        | <--- the real content end here, below is overflowing  
      (X 150vh)  /_________| (100% 150vh)
      
      X = 0 - tan(14deg)*150vh
  */
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <p class="left">
    Some text spanning multiple lines
  </p>
  <p class="right">
    Some text spanning multiple lines
  </p>
</section>
```

**UPDATE**

The first code without `clip-path` for better support:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh; /* dynamic height */
  background:blue;
  overflow:hidden; /* hide the overflow of the big shape */
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
}
.container > * {
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container > *:last-child {
  background:orange;
  position: relative;
}
.container > *:last-child::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  right:calc(100% - 0.5px); /* a litte less than 100% to avoid a gap issue */
  top:0;
  height:130vh; /* a big height, 100vh should be enough but a bit bigger won't hurt */
  width:calc(130vh * 0.249328); /* height x tan(14deg) */
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,orange 50%); /* triangle shape */
  
  opacity:0.9; /* to illustrate the shape */
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <p class="left">
    Some text spanning multiple lines
  </p>
  <p class="right">
    Some text spanning multiple lines
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: So the idea is to create that tilted shape way higher than it needs to be, and then clip it's height using `clip-path`, right? I just don't understand yet, how do you accomplish that the horizontal position is right, but I'm reading that still...

Comment: @RobertKusznier it's easy, first consider it as a rectangle .. you place it on the left of your element using right:100% and top:0 then you make a big height to overflow and you calculate the width considering the height and finally I cut the shape in the diagonal to get my triangle

Comment: @RobertKusznier I have also added another idea with less of code

Comment: Yeah, everything looks clear to me now. The only problem is that from what I see `clip-path` hasn't been supported by Edge until January 2020: https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path :/

Comment: @RobertKusznier I can replace the clip-path with something else, will update

Comment: If you can figure out some better supported solution, it'd be great :).

Comment: Looks good, but unfortunately the support for `polygon()` in Edge seems to be the same as for `clip-path()` - only available since January 2020: https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20polygon :/

Comment: But I think I'll use that solution. On non-supporting Edge versions it should display with a straight line instead of tilted, which I'll just treat as graceful degradation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RobertKusznier I meant the last update, there is 3 snipet in the answer

Comment: You're right, the last snippet doesn't use `clip-path()` and works the same. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219374/discussion-between-robert-kusznier-and-temani-afif).

Comment: I unaccepted the answer, because I've realized the above solutions have one important problem: The distance of left and right elements from the tilted line in the center is not the same. It should be the same, which is visible on the original image.

Comment: @RobertKusznier look at your illustration and where you have placed the 50% value. It's clear the the skewed element should start before the 50% of the second element which will clearly make the distance different. I simply considered your requirements

Comment: Yes, the element on the left will be visually smaller than the one on the right. BUT the distance of the text contents of the left element from the tilted line, and the distance of the text contents of the right element from that same line should be identical, as they are on the image. And in this solution they are not: left text contents are closer to the tilted line that the right text contents. In other words the right padding of the left element and the left padding of the right element should be equal visually. Do you agree that aspect is different than on the image?

Comment: This image shows the problem: https://i.ibb.co/HhCS03m/Screenshot-2020-08-07-ZEWYMRE.png. The text in the blue column almost touches the line, while the text in the orange one sits much further from the line. The distance of both texts from the line should be identical. Here is a pen with your solution and from which that screenshot was taken: https://codepen.io/no-cheating/pen/ZEWYMRE.

Comment: @RobertKusznier will the text define the height of the container? if it's the case, then what you want is impossible because we run into an infinite loop. (1) The text will define the height (2) the shape will get its height from the container (3) the angle is fixed so we get the x (4) the x is reduced from the width of the left element (5) the size of the text inthe left element will then change and we are back to (1)

Comment: Yes, the text will define the text of the container. And yes, it seems it might not be possible at all. If you are interested, a guy on SitePoint forums gave me a solution that's only a little different from the designs, but it displays things without any issues: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-position-a-tilted-skewed-shape-of-unknown-height-in-css/356007. Still big thanks for your help!